# x509: ECDSA verification failure

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have to install a bna file on fabric . I am following the link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org.html . However when I run the command: `composer runtime install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -n tutorial-network`

I am getting the error :

> Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers.

Response from attempted peer comms was an error:

> Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The supplied
>   identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by
>   unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification
>   failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate
>   "ca.org1.example.com").

Any help on this please

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you have made an error in following the tutorial (which definitely works).  Are you sure the MSP id (Org1MSP) for the peer has been setup correctly ? Have you checked that the peer has successfully joined the channel (when the Fabric was started)? Have you done a `docker ps` to see your Fabric docker containers are running?) Assuming you followed the steps correct and using an identity you have obtained from a fabric-ca server (per the tutorial), have you checked the fabric-ca server is running correctly (docker logs  ? Also, is it possible you're restarted your Fabric docker environment at one point and now your old key information is invalid?

eg

```json
{
  "name": "fabric-network",
  "type": "hlfv1",
  "mspID": "Org1MSP",
  "peers": [
      {
          "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
          "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
      }
  ],
  "ca": {
      "url": "http://localhost:7054",
      "name": "ca.org1.example.com"
  },
  "orderers": [
      {
          "url" : "grpc://localhost:7050"
      }
  ],
  "channel": "composerchannel",
  "timeout": 300
}
```

then re-create the card with the correct key/signcert info

```bash
composer card create -p connection.json -u PeerAdmin -c Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k xxxxx_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin
```

where the .pem file comes from `signcerts` directory and xxxxx is the generated value for the key filename in `keystore`.